# Mule outbound properties not available in second calling flow

Tags: mule, mule-el

If from mule flowA, I am making http-request call to flow B and flow C sequential. I have set outbound-properties in Flow A, which I am getting as inbound-properties in flowB but not in Flow C? Is it expected? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned call is from FlowA making http-request call to flow B and flow C sequential but can didn't mentioned how is Flow C called after Flow B. Scenarios

1) FlowA calls FlowC through http request
2) FlowA calls FlowC through Flow Reference
3) FlowB calls FlowC through http request
4) FlowB calls FlowC through Flow Reference.

If its case 3 then obvious the original outbound properties are lost.

Answer (score 0):

That is a expected behavior of Outbound properties.

Reference: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/

Copied main point for quick reference:

Mule Outbound properties can be set by you.
When crossing a “transport barrier”, outbound properties are automatically turned into inbound properties, and no longer exist as outbound properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value available throughout the whole flow use the invocation scope (set-variable to set, flowVars[] to read it).